# ActiveAdmin setting config.logout_link_path cause undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin gem. I want to add a logout link for the menu. So in ActiveAdmin's config file I wrote:

```
config.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
```

And in my `application_controller.rb` I add a method:

```
  def destroy_admin_user_session_path
    session[:current_admin] = nil
    return "/"
  end
```

And back to the ActiveAdmin config I add the menu item:

```
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :defaut do |menu|
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu, html_options: {target: :blank}
    end
  end
```

Then launch my app but when I visit the admin page I got an internal error:

```
undefined method `destroy_admin_user_session_path' for "        <ul class=\"header-item tabs\" id=\"utility_nav\"></ul>\n":ActiveAdmin::Views::TabbedNavigation
```

It seems that the symbol `:destroy_admin_user_session_path` is not send to my `ApplicationController` but something displayed as `<ul class=\"header-item tabs\" id=\"utility_nav\"></ul>\n`.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* (there's not enough code to tell) that what you want is a *view* helper, not a controller method. This would allow you to use the method in your views, which is likely where the HTML it's reporting as the error source is.

Move your `destroy_admin_user_session_path` method to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` and try again.

If you really want to keep your method in the controller, you can alternatively add `helper_method :destroy_admin_user_session_path` to the top of the `ApplicationController` class, which turns the method into a helper method available across controllers and views.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is useful for me.

Comment: I'm a newer to RoR, but I'm really getting mad. It seems to be no document on how to do everything. All I have is the API of RoR and ActiveAdmin. Of course I know [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) and [ActiveAdmin document](https://activeadmin.info/) but they are so brief to cover most of the features (in fact I think they just cover the few basic features). And I can't find any guidance for most things I want to do. For example where should I put `destroy_admin_user_session_path`? Do you have any advice? (If I may ask). Sincerely thanks!

Comment: Convention would dictate putting it in `app/helpers/application_helpers.rb`, @cosmozhang.

Comment: I mean no offense. But in my opinion, convention should be a set of rules that you can either obey (for more organized developing) or not obey. And not obeying will cause no error. This idea is what I get when using some other web frameworks. However if I don't follow these conventions in RoR or ActiveAdmin I can't get my app work. So I think it is not a convention but a protocol, which should be written clearly somewhere (documents, guidance, etc.). But no one tells me what should be done and what not. And if I went into errors it just tells me I'm wrong and not telling me what's correct.

Comment: There's a solution to that, @cosmozhang - follow convention. It may still mostly work if you don't, but it does you no harm to follow it - and most of it has been done that way for good reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree to that following convention is better. But my problem is that I don't know what is the convention for Rails. Maybe I need a tutorial book for Rails? But can a book tell me everything I need? And what about ActiveAdmin (or other gems)? I don't know a book about ActiveAdmin. Really thx for your help.

Comment: Best advice I can give you is to look up the documentation whenever you're not sure - that usually has relevant details